# find and replace with the value in another file

Tags: files, awk

I have two files with different formats with columns tab spaced. I have to compare the columns `column1`, `column2` of `file1` with `file2`. If they matches, I need to replace the value in `column6` of `file1` with the value in `column3` of `file2`. I have tried using `awk` but I am not able to replace the value. Could you please advise on the below snippet ?

```
awk 'FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
    m[$1,$2] = $6;
    next;
}
{
    if (($1,$2) in m) {
        m[$6]= $3; print m[$6];
    }
}' file1 file2


top few lines of file1
1201 12011 1 0 0 0 1
1202 12021 1 0 0 0 1
1203 12031 1 0 0 0 1
1204 12041 1 0 0 0 2
1207 12071 1 0 0 0 2
1209 12091 1 0 0 0 1
1210 12101 1 0 0 0 1
1212 12121 1 0 0 0 1
1213 12131 1 0 0 0 1
1214 12141 1 0 0 0 2

top few lines of file2
1201    12011   1
1202    12021   1
1203    12031   1
1204    12041   1
1206    NA  1
1207    12071   2
1208    NA  1
1209    12091   2
1210    12101   2
```

I want to assign the values from file2 to file1 column as I would like to write the updated content into another file `out.txt`

## edit

Tried the below code as per the comments

```
awk '{
    if (FNR==NR) {
        a[FNR]=$1;b[FNR]=$2;c[FNR]=$3}
    else {             
        if (a[FNR] == $1 && b[FNR] ==$2) {
            $6=c[FNR]} else {$6=$6};
           print $0;
        }
    }' file2 file1
```

Got this output

```
1201 12011 1 0 0 1 1
1202 12021 1 0 0 1 1
1203 12031 1 0 0 1 1
1204 12041 1 0 0 1 2
1207 12071 1 0 0 0 2
1209 12091 1 0 0 0 1
1210 12101 1 0 0 0 1
1212 12121 1 0 0 0 1
1213 12131 1 0 0 0 1
1214 12141 1 0 0 0 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '{
    if (FNR==NR) {
        a[FNR]=$1;b[FNR]=$2;c[FNR]=$3}
    else {
        if (a[FNR] == $1 && b[FNR] ==$2) {
            $6=c[FNR]} else {$6=$6};
            print $0
        }
    }' file2 file1
```

I think this will do the work. First it will save the 1st,2nd and 3rd column of file 2 to array `a`,`b` and `c` resp with index as `FNR` if `FNR = NR`(true for lines in file2 only). Else(true for lines in file1 only) compare value in array `a` and `b` with `$1` and `$2`. if it matches change the 6th field with value in array `c` else it will reassign the value to same and prints the line with delimiter as `tab`.

Comment: Thank you. It's not working for my files. I could see the comparison is being done by 1st line file1 with 1st line of file2. It is not matching the lines if their line numbers are different. I am not sure if my observation is right.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative non-`awk` sledgehammer approach

```
while read f1 f2 f3; do 
    sed -E -i "s/^($f1\s+$f2.*)([0-9]+)$/\1$f3/" file1;
done < file2
```

Assumes the last number is a integer. If it isn't then `([0-9])$` will need amending to a suitable capture group.

Note that this relies on modifying file1 in-situ so work on a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your awk script, you've got the right idea about processing each input file differently (although in most cases checking if `NR == FNR` works better and faster because numeric comparisons are faster than string comparisons...which would be significant if there were many thousands of input lines in either or both files).

There are a few problems, though, that prevent your script from doing what you want.

1. You're reading the files in the wrong order - since you want to output lines from file1 with column 6 replaced by column 3 of file2, you need to read file2 first to build up the `m` array (with indexes of `$1,$2` from file2 and values of `$3` from file2).
2. You're modifying `m[$6]` and then printing it. At best, this will print a single column.

Try something like this:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR    { m[$1,$2] = $3; next }
       ($1,$2) in m { $6 = m[$1,$2] }
       1' file2 file1
1201 12011 1 0 0 1 1
1202 12021 1 0 0 1 1
1203 12031 1 0 0 1 1
1204 12041 1 0 0 1 2
1207 12071 1 0 0 2 2
1209 12091 1 0 0 2 1
1210 12101 1 0 0 2 1
1212 12121 1 0 0 0 1
1213 12131 1 0 0 0 1
1214 12141 1 0 0 0 2
```

Alternatively, replace the `NR == FNR` on the first line with your original `FILENAME == ARGV[1]`.

For every line of `file2` (the first file to be read - note the order of filename arguments on the command line) it stores $3 in the array `m` and skips to the next input line.  Columns `$1` and `$2` are used as the index for the array.

Then, while reading `file1` (and subsequent input files, if any), if `($1,$2)` is an index in the array, it replaces `$6` with the value stored in the `m` array.

Then it prints the current input line whether it was modified or not (a pattern of `1` by itself is an awk idiom/shortcut meaning "print the current input line" - "1" evaluates as true, and the default action is "print"...so, effectively "if true is true then print")

Note: you didn't provide sample expected output so I can't verify that the output matches what you want (normally, I like to save an OP's sample output to a file and use `diff` or `cmp` to verify that my output matches).  My awk script's output does match *my interpretation of* what you asked for in your question.